# Spatial autocorrelation of car crashes and traffic safety complaints in python

Tags: python, autocorrelation, spatial

I am admittedly new to spatial autocorrelation and I did this research myself so apologies if this is completely noob behavior. I am trying to determine if there is a correlation between the location of car crashes in NYC and the number of 311 complaints about traffic safety issues within 100 meters. Below is the code, but the results are thus:

Moran's I for Killed: 0.263 p-value for Killed: 0.001

Moran's I for All Crashes: 0.859 p-value for All Crashes: 0.001

Does the Moran calculation need to be in polygons than have shared borders? or can this be correctly calculated with point data? The code I used in the calculations is below

```
radius = libpysal.cg.RADIUS_EARTH_KM

moran_df = pd.read_csv('../data/model_nyc_crash.csv')
moran_df['crash_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(moran_df['crash_datetime'])
drop_cols = ['collision_id', 'crash_datetime', 'unique_id', 'zip_code','rain_1mm','borough', 'injury_type',
            'injury_severity', 'total_commute_population', 'commute_car', 'commute_public_transport',
            'commute_walk', 'commute_other', 'total_population_poverty', 'below_poverty_count', 'cam_type']
moran_df = moran_df.drop(columns=drop_cols)
moran_killed = moran_df[moran_df['crash_severity'] == 'Killed']

moran_df['geometry'] = moran_df['geometry'].apply(wkt.loads)
moran_killed['geometry'] = moran_killed['geometry'].apply(wkt.loads)

gdf_moran_killed = gpd.GeoDataFrame(moran_killed, geometry='geometry')
gdf_moran_total = gpd.GeoDataFrame(moran_df, geometry='geometry')

gdf_list = {"Killed" : gdf_moran_killed, "All Crashes": gdf_moran_total}
print("Spatial autocorrelation analysis of crashes with at least one injury or death and 311 road safety complaints:")
for name, gdf in gdf_list.items():
    w= KNN.from_dataframe(gdf, geom_col='geometry', k=5, radius=radius) 
    w.transform = 'R'

    moran = Moran(gdf['complaints_within100m'], w)

    print(f"Moran's I for {name}:", moran.I)
    print(f"p-value for {name}:", moran.p_sim)
```